# How can I create an Excel table using NPOI XSSF in C#?

Tags: c#, npoi

I want to create a table in excel file using XSSFTable, after many research I can not do. The resources for 'NPOI in c#'  on internet are very unique.

```
 XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("Architecture");

            XSSFTable table = sheet.CreateTable();
            CT_Table cttable =  table.GetCTTable();

            cttable.displayName = "Table1";
            cttable.id = 1;
            cttable.name = "Test";
           // cttable.setRef("A1:C11");
            cttable.totalsRowShown = false;
```

that's what I found but I cannot complete it to insert data inside table .

Comment: I recommend you to use EPPLUS library, it's free to non-comerce use and much better.

Comment: @hamaronooo  I have not a choice to choose which library to use, because the whole project work on NPOI so that they want all reports to work on the same library

Comment: There is an example in GitLab repository but it doesn't work with the latest version of NPOI 2.5.6. https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/blob/main/xssf/CreateTableInXlsx/Program.cs